# How to change the hash in the URL dynamically when i scroll over components in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

i have a one page vue.js app with a number of components, now i want to change the hash dynamically in the url when i scroll through the components. An example would be if you try to scroll in the vue.js docs:

You will find the url changing when scrolling from this:

```
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#what-is-vue-js
```

To this:

```
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#getting-started
```

and so on.

I tried making `@scroll="changeRoute"` on the first tag of my component and this triggers a function:

```
<script>
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
export default {
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const changeRoute = () => {
      router.push({
        name: "Home",
        hash: "#landing-section",
      });
      console.log("route changes");
    };
    return {
      changeRoute,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Bu this didn't work, the function in not even executing ?

Comment: Chances are, your component is not triggering the scroll event. You should be attaching the scroll event to the scrollable parent (likely the html/body element). Also, you might want to consider using IntersectionObserver, and checking which component is currently intersecting the viewport: then update the hash to an identifier associated with the component instead.

Comment: I will search it

Comment: "How can I do that?" What I said in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you get started and because you provided the vue documentation as an example, you can just see how it works on their page.

They used a package called [VuePress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org) which has a [setActiveHash](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/blob/38e98634af117f83b6a32c8ff42488d91b66f663/packages/%40vuepress/plugin-active-header-links/clientRootMixin.js) function.

It looks like they `debounce` the scroll event, then get all the elements that they would want to change the hash with using `querySelectorAll`, then find if those elements are active and then replacing the current hash with the active element hash.

```
/* global AHL_SIDEBAR_LINK_SELECTOR, AHL_HEADER_ANCHOR_SELECTOR */

import debounce from 'lodash.debounce'

export default {
  mounted () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
  },

  methods: {
    onScroll: debounce(function () {
      this.setActiveHash()
    }, 300),

    setActiveHash () {
      const sidebarLinks = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(AHL_SIDEBAR_LINK_SELECTOR))
      const anchors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(AHL_HEADER_ANCHOR_SELECTOR))
        .filter(anchor => sidebarLinks.some(sidebarLink => sidebarLink.hash === anchor.hash))

      const scrollTop = Math.max(
        window.pageYOffset,
        document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        document.body.scrollTop
      )

      const scrollHeight = Math.max(
        document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        document.body.scrollHeight
      )

      const bottomY = window.innerHeight + scrollTop

      for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        const anchor = anchors[i]
        const nextAnchor = anchors[i + 1]

        const isActive = i === 0 && scrollTop === 0
          || (scrollTop >= anchor.parentElement.offsetTop + 10
            && (!nextAnchor || scrollTop < nextAnchor.parentElement.offsetTop - 10))

        const routeHash = decodeURIComponent(this.$route.hash)
        if (isActive && routeHash !== decodeURIComponent(anchor.hash)) {
          const activeAnchor = anchor
          // check if anchor is at the bottom of the page to keep $route.hash consistent
          if (bottomY === scrollHeight) {
            for (let j = i + 1; j < anchors.length; j++) {
              if (routeHash === decodeURIComponent(anchors[j].hash)) {
                return
              }
            }
          }
          this.$vuepress.$set('disableScrollBehavior', true)
          this.$router.replace(decodeURIComponent(activeAnchor.hash), () => {
            // execute after scrollBehavior handler.
            this.$nextTick(() => {
              this.$vuepress.$set('disableScrollBehavior', false)
            })
          })
          return
        }
      }
    }
  },

  beforeDestroy () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
  }
}
```